# Is there a better way to check type of input parameter in php?

Tags: php

I want to check that the $duration is object of type DateInterval otherwise throw an exception. get_class function fails if $duration is not an object... and this code looks to long

```
        if (is_object($duration)) {
            if (get_class($duration) != "DateInterval") {
                throw new \Exception('The provided duration is not DateInterval type.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('The provided duration is not DateInterval type.');
        }
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: you can shorten it to  if (is_object($duration) && !($duration instanceof DateInterval)

Comment: Type hints http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `instanceof` method. See the example:

```
$obj = new A();

if ($obj instanceof A) {
    echo 'A';
}
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `instanceof`:

```
if (!$duration instanceof DateInterval) {
    // throw Exception
}
```

Comment: correct your negation - it should be like that: if (!($duration instanceof DateInterval))